# How to set valueUpdate binding globally in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I just started using knockoutjs and I couldn't find a way to bind valueUpdate on afterkeydown for all the input fields at once. Is there a way to do that or do I really have to add valueUpdate: afterKeyDown to every input fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this binding provider plugin

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider

Or you can create a custom binding

http://jsfiddle.net/4jRKV/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.value2 = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: valueAccessor(), valueUpdate: "afterkeydown" });
    }
};
```